# Ordering div elements based on properties of associated objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, html

I have an array of objects `box[]`, and a `div` element for each of these objects with class `.box`. Each object has a numeric property `box[].id`, which is used to identify the corresponding `div` element which has the same `id` attribute. I want to create a function to order the `div` elements based on other properties of their related objects, I think it would be something like this using JavaScript and jQuery:

```
// Call my order function based on property1 for example.    
sortBox("property1");    

function sortBox(property) {
    var order;
    $(".box").each(function (i) {
        // Gets the property on which to sort for each div
        order = box[this.id][property];
        //////////////////////
        //.......????.......//
        //////////////////////
    });
}
```

This gets the property for each `div` to do the sorting but I have no idea what to do after to order the divs based on that property and update the Html. Please help, what is the proper way to do this? Any ideas, examples, suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came up with this:

```
// the prop param is the object property used to sort the array of objects.
function sortBox(prop) {
    box.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Then I can call my `sortBox` function to sort my `box[]` array based on any of the properties of its objects. Then I delete the existing `<div>` elements with jQuery empty() and create them again with the array sorted:

```
$("#boxcontainer").empty();

// the html property specifies the <div> html
for (var i = 0, len = box.length; i < len; i++) {
    $("#boxcontainer").append(box[i].html);
}
```

Comment: :) looks an awful lot like my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the `sort()`-function, e.g.:

```
var boxes = $(".box");
// convert boxes to a regular array
boxes.sort(sortFunc);

function sortFunc(div1, div2) {
     // please note that the result is in descending order (see below)
     // if div1 > div2 return -1
     // if div1 < div2 return 1
     // if div1 == div2 return 0
}
```

Then you can run a loop to insert each `DIV` as the first element before the first child of the parent

```
boxes.each(
    function(el) {
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(el, el.parentNode.firstChild);
    });
```

Because the `boxes` are sorted descending you end up with the "smallest" element in the first position.

*This might contain syntax errors!*

Comment: I was going to post something using the .sort() function, but you beat me to it. The syntax looks fine, by the way.

Comment: But by doing it this way it is not sorted by the properties of the associated object to that div but by the contents of it, right?

Comment: @VerizonW: I don't know exactly what you want to compare, so I lined out how you could do this. Whatever you want to compare goes into `sortFunc()`. AFAIK it's not possible to pass additional parameters to the sorting function, which is why you would need to use e.g. global variables if you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the other direction.

1. Convert `box` to an array.
2. Use the built in `array.sort`
3. clear the container and append the elements in order from sorted array.

> ```
> var boxArray = [];
> for (var b in box)
>     boxArray.push({id: b, box: b});
>
> boxArray = boxArray.sort(function (a, b) {
>     if (a.box.prop1 < b.box.prop1)
>         return -1;
>     else if (a.box.prop1 > b.box.prop1)
>         return 1;
>     return 0;
> });
> ```

Box array is now sorted and you can clone/copy elements into a new container.

Comment: Actually box[] is already an array of objects so maybe I don't need to create a new array ands just sort the existing one.